# How to retrieve the list of data under 1 child in Firebase Database in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Data stored in firebase:

```
 29-06-2018(date)

     -AAAA
           -25142(jobno)
           -Park station(address)
           -BMW(model)

     -BBBB 
           -85142(jobno)
           -Base station(address)
           -Ford(model)
```

Here I want all the children under -BBBB. Don't want to loop through AAAA. How to get directly the child of BBBB. I'm having data (date, BBBB). Just want to get jobno, address, model of BBBB. Please suggest me a solution.

My code is here

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference pwd = database.child("29-06-2018").child("BBBB");

        pwd.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {    
                        String a = ds.child("jobno").getValue(String.class);
                        String b = ds.child("address").getValue(String.class);
                        String c = ds.child("model").getValue(String.class);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're listening to a single child `/29-06-2018/BBBB`. By looping over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` you're looping over each property, and then try to reach a child property for each. That won't work, so you should get rid of the loop in `onDataChange`:

```
pwd.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot ds) {
        String a = ds.child("jobno").getValue(String.class);
        String b = ds.child("address").getValue(String.class);
        String c = ds.child("model").getValue(String.class);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and quick response. just a small change in your code not "ds" its "dataSnapshot" .

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference pwd = database.child("29-06-2018").child("BBBB");

        pwd.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        String a = dataSnapshot.child("jobno").getValue(String.class);
                        String b = dataSnapshot.child("address").getValue(String.class);
                        String c = dataSnapshot.child("model").getValue(String.class);


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            }

        });
```